# The media queries for h2 and h3 are not applying. How can I fix this?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive

I am trying to add media queries for h2 and h3 in my code but when viewing it on safari developer preview I can't see any changes. Even not after refreshing the page and saving the code. The queries don't apply. I have tried putting the queries directly after then non-query section but its still not working. How can I solve this problem?

```js
const menuToggle = document.querySelector('.toggle');
        const showcase = document.querySelector('.showcase');

        menuToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
          menuToggle.classList.toggle('active');
          showcase.classList.toggle('active');
        })
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900&display=swap');
*
{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}


.hero-section-wrapper {
   position: relative;
   height: 100vh;
   display: table;
   width: 100%;
}


header
{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 40px 100px;
 z-index: 1000;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
}
header .logo
{
 color: #fff;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.toggle
{
 position: relative;
 width: 60px;
 height: 60px;
 background: url(https://i.ibb.co/HrfVRcx/menu.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 30px;
 background-position: center;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.toggle.active
{
 background: url(https://i.ibb.co/rt3HybH/close.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 25px;
 background-position: center;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.showcase
{
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 width: 100%;
 min-height: 100vh;
 padding: 100px;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
 background: #000000;
 transition: 0.5s;
 color: #ffff;
 z-index: 2;

}
.showcase.active
{
 right: 300px;
}



.showcase video
{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 object-fit: cover;
 opacity: 0.8;
}
.overlay
{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: #0394f4;
 mix-blend-mode: overlay;
 color: #001540;
}
.text
{
 position: relative;
 z-index: 10;
}

.text h2
{
 font-size: 3em;
 font-weight: 800;
 color: #fff;
 line-height: 1em;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
.text h3
{
 font-size: 7em;
 font-weight: 700;
 color: #64A8F0;
 line-height: 1em;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

.text p
{
 font-size: 1.1em;
 color: #fff;
 margin: 20px 0;
 font-weight: 400;
 max-width: 700px;
}
.text a
{
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 1em;
 background: #fff;
 padding: 10px 30px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: 500;
 margin-top: 10px;
 color: #111;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
 transition: 0.2s;
}
.text a:hover
{
 letter-spacing: 6px;
}



.social
{
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 10;
 bottom: 20px;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}
.social li
{
 list-style: none;
}
.social li a
{
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 20px;
 filter: invert(1);
 transform: scale(0.5);
 transition: 0.5s;
}
.social li a:hover
{
 transform: scale(0.5) translateY(-15px);
}


.menu
{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 width: 300px;
 height: 100%;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 background-color: #000026;

}
.menu ul
{
 position: relative;
}
.menu ul li
{
 list-style: none;
}
.menu ul li a
{
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 24px;
 color: #ffff;
}
.menu ul li a:hover
{
 color: #64A8F0;
}




.section{
   width: 100%;
   min-height: 60vh;
   background-color: #64A8F0;
}
.container{
   width: 80%;
   display: block;
   margin:auto;
   padding-top: 75px;
}
.content-section{
   float: left;
   width: 55%;
}
.image-section{
   float: right;
   width: 40%;
}
.image-section img{
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}
.content-section .title{
   text-transform: uppercase;
   font-size: 28px;
}
.content-section .content h3{
   margin-top: 8px;
   color:#0703d0;
   font-size: 21px;
}
.content-section .content p{
   margin-top: 10px;

   font-size: 16px;
   line-height: 1.5;
}
.content-section .content .button{
   margin-top: 30px;
}
.content-section .content .button a{
   background-color: #3d3d3d;
   padding:12px 40px;
   text-decoration: none;
   color:#fff;
   font-size: 25px;
   letter-spacing: 1.5px;
}
.content-section .content .button a:hover{
   background-color: #a52a2a;
   color:#fff;
}
.content-section .social{
   margin: 40px 40px;
}
.content-section .social i{
   color:#a52a2a;
   font-size: 30px;
   padding:0px 10px;
}
.content-section .social i:hover{
   color:#3d3d3d;
}

   <!--===== Media Queries =====--!>

@media screen and (max-width: 768px){

   .container{
   width: 80%;
   display: block;
   margin:auto;
   padding-top:60px;
      height: 30vh;
}

.content-section{
   float:none;
   width:100%;
   display: block;
   margin:auto;
}
.image-section{
   float:none;
   width:0%;

}
.image-section img{
   width: 100%;
   height: 30vh;
   display: block;
   margin:auto;
}
.content-section .title{
   text-align: inherit;
   font-size: 19px;
   padding-top: 27px;
}
.content-section .social{
   text-align: center;
}



@media (max-width: 991px){

 .showcase,
 .showcase header
 {
   padding: 40px;
 }
 .text h2
 {
   font-size: 2em;
 }
 .text h3
 {
   font-size: 40em;
 }


 @media screen and (max-width: 768px){
   .text h2
   {
     font-size: 1em;
   }
   .text h3
   {
     font-size: 3em;
   }
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
  <title>Think Tank</title>

</html>
<head>

</head>

<body>
  <style>
      @import url('ultra.css');
  </style>

<div class="hero-section-wrapper">
    <section class="showcase">

       <header>
         <h2 class="logo"></h2>
         <div class="toggle"></div>
       </header>

       <video src="webasset.mov" muted loop autoplay></video>
       <div class="overlay"></div>
           <div class="text">
             <h2>Willkommen auf </h2>
             <h3>Think Tank</h3>
             <p>Beispiel.</p>
             <a href="#">THINK kaufen</a>
           </div>
           <ul class="social">
             <li><a href="#"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/x7P24fL/facebook.png"></a></li>
             <li><a href="https://twitter.com/ThinkTank__?t=RxrP3KIpS8-L6UOfjpd7Ww&s=08"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/Wnxq2Nq/twitter.png"></a></li>
             <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/think.tank.official/"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/ySwtH4B/instagram.png"></a></li>
           </ul>
    </section>
    </div>
     <div class="menu">
       <ul>
         <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="section">Unser Token</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">NFT (COMING SOON)</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Das Team</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
       </ul>
     </div>


    <div class="section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="content-section">
                <div class="title">
                    <h1>THINK TOKEN</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <h3>Passives Einkommen leicht gemacht...</h3>
                <p>Unser DeFi Token generiert automatisiert passives Einkommen
                  indem 2% jeder Transaktion an alle Besitzer des Tokens verteilt werden.
                  Weitere 2% fliessen in einen Liquiditaets-Pool um unseren Token ein
                  Fundament am Markt zu bieten.
                </p>

                </div>
                <div class="social">
                    <a href=""><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
                    <a href=""><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
                    <a href=""><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="image-section">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1640525999004-42b645dd3dee?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


             <!--===== MAIN JS =====-->
           <script src="ultra.js"></script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You didn't close 991px media query.

Answer (score 0):

You forget curly bracket `}` on media queries.

- Line 319 missing `}`